# Unable to connect to Linux Ubuntu Azure VM using public IP address

Tags: networking, nginx

Unable to connect to Linux Ubuntu Azure VM using public IP address.

I have tried everything.

1. have 'ufw' active and allowed port 80

```
username@LinuxLR:\~$ sudo ufw status

Status: active

&#x200B;

To                         Action      From

\--                         ------      ----

80                         ALLOW       Anywhere

443                        ALLOW       Anywhere

Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere

80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

2. done something I found about hard-enabling traffic on port 80

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

3. tested with local host. "curl localhost" grabs the html on the page. "curl public ip address" doesn't give a response. Literally nothing happens.

`username@LinuxLR:\~$ curl http://127.0.0.1/`

````
<html>

<head>

<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>

<style>

body {

width: 35em;

margin: 0 auto;

font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>

<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and

working. Further configuration is required.</p>


<p>For online documentation and support please refer to

<a href="[http://nginx.org/](http://nginx.org/)">nginx.org</a>.<br/>

Commercial support is available at

<a href="[http://nginx.com/](http://nginx.com/)">nginx.com</a>.</p>


<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>

</body>

</html>```


4. Similar thing with wget. "wget localhost" grabs the usual nginx html page. "wget public ip address" does:

```username@LinuxLR:\~$ wget "public ip address"

\--2022-10-19 19:40:43--  "public ip address"

Connecting to "public ip address"... failed: Connection timed out.

Retrying.
````

Comment: I see you allowed IP 6 but you are trying to use IP 4?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between them. In what way am I trying to use IP 4 instead of IP 6?

Comment: username@LinuxLR:\~$ curl http://127.0.0.1/ An IP 4 address. I suggest you do some research on what IP 4 and 6 are and the differences. You have specified IP 6 in the UFW rules without understanding what IP 6 is?